# Nestjs: @Session() return undefined

Tags: express, nestjs

I am currently migrating my server to use nest.js.
When I use the `@Session()` decorator it gives me undefined.
I do import it from @nestjs/common, this is not the issue.

```
@Get('foo')
async find(@Session() sess) {
  console.log(sess); // sess == undefined
}
```

While, with express the session is defined

```
router.get('/foo/', function(req, res){
  console.log(req.session); // req.session is defined
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [session](https://github.com/expressjs/session) middleware is not applied by default, you have to do it manually:

```
app.use(session({ secret: 'nest is awesome' }))
```